# What is the best way to handle parallel telnet connections?

Tags: perl, parallels

What is the best way to handle parallel telnet connections to cisco devices via Perl. 
I need to open several telnet connections to keep in background and to feed commands 
in interactive or timed batch way. Is this possible to do it with the anyevent or POE libraries?

Thanks.

Comment: 10 till 20.000 tcp connections.

Answer (score 1):

Threads are a headache. An event loop, such as AnyEvent, is much simpler and more performant, specially if you want to submit commands in a timed fashion and need to handle thousand of connections.

See AnyEvent::Socket on how to open a connection and read & write data: [http://metacpan.org/pod/AnyEvent::Socket](http://metacpan.org/pod/AnyEvent%3a%3aSocket)

You could also use Net::Telnet on top of it, as supports using an already opened filehandle: [http://metacpan.org/pod/Net::Telnet#fhopen](http://metacpan.org/pod/Net%3a%3aTelnet#fhopen)

If you run into trouble with AnyEvent, just ask a new question.

Comment: how to reconnect with anyevent? what should main program do while callbacks are performing IO?

Comment: You can decide what to do if tcp_connect fails: either retry or just log an error. The main loop waits while connections are working, but there's no need to explicitly do something.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is to use treads. You could use 'queues' to send commands and receive outputs back and forth.

You could simply create x number of threads, then queue a lot of commands and send them.

If you need to process the output, is a bit trickier.

[http://metacpan.org/pod/Thread::Queue](http://metacpan.org/pod/Thread%3a%3aQueue)

It could be solved by event based modules as well but that one needs a very different approach. This way you could create a not threaded function then convert it into threaded one easily.

```
#without processing the output
use strict;
use warnings;

use threads;
use Thread::Queue;

my $q = Thread::Queue->new();    # A new empty queue
my $maxThreads = 20;
# Create Worker threads
for (1..$maxThreads){
  my $thr = threads->create(
    sub {
        # Thread will loop until no more work
        while (defined(my $cmd = $q->dequeue())) {
            do_someting($cmd);
        }
    }
  );
}

# Send work to the threads
$q->enqueue($cmd1, ...);
# Signal that there is no more work to be sent
$q->end();
# Join up with the thread when it finishes
$thr->join();
```